# Check boxes and Tabs in CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, customization, crm

I have 3 checkboxes (A,B,C) and 3 tabs (A,B,C). When 'A' is checked, tab A needs to be open (Tab B and C needs to be closed). When 'B' is checked (tab A and C needs to be closed, tab B needs to be open. How can I achieve this?. Does anyone have a function I can use.

Comment: You already asked substantially the same question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24417859/making-a-section-on-crm-2011-form-required. You should edit that question for clarity if the answers you are receiving are not sufficient. Creating a new questions clutters up StackOverflow and is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `form Properties` of the `entity` on which you have `CheckBoxes` and `Tabs` :

Select `Checkbox A`, click on `Change Properties` and then make your own function like  below named `MakeTabsRequired`:

[image]

now in function `MakeTabsRequired`

```
function MakeTabsRequired()
{
//string TabA =Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("A").getDisplayState()
//string TabB =Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("B").getDisplayState()
//string TabC =Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("C").getDisplayState()

if(Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("CheckboxA").getAttribute().getValue()=true)
{

Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("A").setDisplayState('expanded');
Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("B").setDisplayState('collapsed');
Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("C").setDisplayState('collapsed');

}
else
{

Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("A").setDisplayState('collapsed');
Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("B").setDisplayState('expanded');
Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("C").setDisplayState('expanded');

}
}
```

**Here the Control named "Shipping same as Billing Info" is a CheckBox, and I have attached the function to OnChange of the CheckBox**

`Similarly attach function to OnChange of Checkbox B and C`

Comment: Thank you. I tried this function but I get the following error "cannot assign to a function result"

Comment: @user3429723 I think i missed the `Closing` bracket of function